# Menu in Bootstrap 4 disappears when the mouse movement is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm running [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/o23865p6/) and when the mouse pointer moves quickly from from START to the unfolded menu, everything works great. However, when the movement is slower, the menu closes because it feels like the mouse's left.

```
const menu = $("li.dropdown");
menu.on("mouseenter mouseleave", () => {
  menu.toggleClass("open");
});
```

Initially, I tried to make the list item control taller but realized quickly that the menu will open **below it** (plus this unfortunate vertical distance).

What can I do about it?

Apparently Bootstrap creators found this good for some reason (or didn't think about mouse movements but rather clicking). Am I setting up the hover event in an inappropriate way, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for me is better this solution

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/pyrh24ve/) is the fiddle

```
.open>.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top: initial;
}
```

Comment: Can you discuss pros/cons of it compared to the suggestion of  @pavelstreba ?

Comment: @KonradViltersten
pavelstreba use calc and I quote from mozilla documentation
calc: 
This is an experimental technology
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.
here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Hmm... Definitely +1. I'll try your and his in a range of browsers. Very good point, mate.

Comment: @KonradViltersten careful that maybe it work fine right now but as mozilla say it can change in future versions of browsers, and that is why this solution is better, because in time the other can fail but this not

Comment: Good suggestion. Both are interesting but I'm prone to go with yours based on your motivation. I've never used *initial* in CSS (and I've been doing web since many, many years) so I'm happy to break the virginity, hehe. I'd like to suggest that you mention shortly what *initial* does to the component in a bit more generalized way, possibly a link to docs, or something. That would make your answer awesome for future confused coders, I believe. The answer as of now is still good enough for me so it's accepted. But you might want to fish for future rep votes, hehe.

Comment: I've noticed that the solution works perfectly in FF and Cr but in IE, while the gap got considerably smaller, it still gets in the way. Your answer is accepted but you're welcome to take a peek at [that specific gotcha for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322119/internet-explorer-keeps-a-tiny-whiney-vertical-gap-causing-mouseout-when-pointe).

Answer (score 2):

This css fixed it for me (Bootstrap v4.3.1):

```
div.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's caused with space between menu element and menu itself. When you are moving fast, it's ok, because cursor "jumps" directly to menu, but moving slowly, you will leave menu item area and menu disappear. One solution which comes to my mind is to move it 1px higher:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o23865p6/5/).

Comment: I'm very careful on tampering with something created by bigger brains than mine, hehe. Whereas you sugestion is fully working (granting +1), I wonder if it's reasonable to deem the creators of Booty 4 so clumsy as to miss such an annoyance. I'm certain they haven't decided - "*hey, guys, let's leave a vertical space here to dick around with slow moving people...*" and I fear that perhaps I'm doing something else wrongly. What's your take on it?

Comment: Also, what do you think of the suggestion made by Emiliano below?