# Internet Explorer keeps a tiny, whiney vertical gap causing mouseout when pointer moves slowly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, firefox, bootstrap-4

I asked [about the vertical gap causing *mouseout* on slow pointer movement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41316501/1525840) and the issue got resolved (two separate approaches). However, I noticed that the corrected behavior only applies to FF and Cr, while IE still keeps a tiny vertical gap. It got much tinier, which is good, but it's still there.

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: initial;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/0a67pyd2/) and compare the behavior between browsers for details.

How can I make IE behave like the other children in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't understand the `initial` value of the `margin-top`:

[image]

You can use `auto` instead:

```
.open>.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here is a fork of your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0a67pyd2/4/

Checked in chrome/firefox/ie.

Comment: Are you saying that IE doesn't support the option *initial* in that context? Or is there another circumstance (Booty related or otherwise brought in) that prevents it from getting the requested behavior? I'm asking because I sensed that the gap got smaller when I used *initial* so the conclusion what that IE could interpret the parameter but got confused by something else. Was I mislead by my expectations, perhaps?

Comment: Added image to the answer :) check it